# Determine Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have the following which is based on a normal distribution having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I tried to find out the distribution of this: $\frac{\sqrt{N}(\bar{X_N}- \mu)}{\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(X_n - \bar{X_N})^2}{(N-1)} }$ In my opinion it could be normally distributed, asymptotically since it is similar to $\frac{\sqrt{N}[\bar{Y_N}-E(Y)]}{\sqrt{V(Y)}}$ but I'm not sure. Would you agree?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very poorly worded question, as you haven't written down what any of the random variables are supposed to be and what assumptions you make on them.

Guessing that you have some independent Gaussian random variables and $\bar{X}_n$ is supposed to be their (empirical) mean, the answer is no. The distribution is a [t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).

Comment: Hi I'm sorry, your are right. $X_n$ is supposed to be the mean $X_N$, and it is based on a normal distribution having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I will edit my original question.

Comment: Can you please clarify why this is a t-distribution?

Comment: This is written in section 2 of the Wikipedia article.